# About the wrong evaluation of an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Here is an integral I've been studying in my research and I've just realized that Mathematica $8.0$ is unable to correctly compute it. I have 2 simple questions to ask:

1. Is my code below correct?

   ```
   Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), {x, 0, 1}]
   ```
2. Are the newer Mathematica versions able to correctly compute it (how about W|A)?

Please do not provide with mathematical solutions, I like to attend this part on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct and v.9 produces a result. If appropriate you can halp things by adding assumptions..for example:

```
     Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), {x, 0, 1}, 
          Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> -PolyGamma[0, a] + PolyGamma[0, b/c]

Indeed.. it apperars to be incorrect..

```
 example = {a -> RandomReal[{0, 2}], b -> RandomReal[{0, 2}], c -> RandomReal[{0, 2}]}
 Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), {x, 0, 1}, 
        Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}] /. example
 Integrate[
     x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c) /. example, {x, 0, 1} ]
 NIntegrate[
     x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c) /. example, {x, 0, 1} ]
```

> {a -> 1.35623, b -> 1.98544, c -> 0.957961}
>
> 0.57579
>
> 0.532842
>
> 0.532842

Edit.. try the indefinite integral :

```
   indef = Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), x, 
         Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]

   Simplify[ Limit[ indef , x -> 1 ] - indef /. x -> 0 , 
       Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0} ]
```

> 1/a + Log[c] - PolyGamma[0, 1 + a] + PolyGamma[0, b/c]

Is that right??  Gives the same numerical result for the example

```
 % /. example // N
```

> 0.532842

Comment: This is a wrong answer, but thanks for your effort. (+1)

Comment: It seems OK, excepting the fact it's not nicely simplified (the answer I mean).

Comment: `FullSimplify` .. gets got there.. same as chuy's answer

Answer (score 3):

Problem looks to occur when doing the definite integral. If you start with the indefinite integral:

```
int = Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), x]

(* x^a/a + (x^(1 + a) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 + a, 2 + a, x])/(1 + a) - 
   (c x^b Hypergeometric2F1[1, b/c, 1 + b/c, x^c])/b *)
```

and you do the limits by hand you get:

```
result=FullSimplify[Limit[int,x-> 1, Assumptions->{a>0,b>0,c>0}]-Limit[int,x-> 0, Assumptions->{a>0,b>0,c>0}]]

(* 1/a + EulerGamma - HarmonicNumber[a] + Log[c] + PolyGamma[0, b/c] *)
```

which looks correct.

```
example = {a -> RandomReal[{0, 2}], b -> RandomReal[{0, 2}], c -> RandomReal[{0, 2}]}

(* {a -> 1.90438, b -> 0.334205, c -> 0.32148} *)

result /. example

(* -2.00794 *)
```

and

```
NIntegrate[x^(a-1)/(1-x)-c x^(b-1)/(1-x^c)/.example,{x,0,1}]

(* -2.00794 *)
```

Comment: OK, thanks for feedback! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer 0 using

```
Integrate[x^(a - 1)/(1 - x) - c x^(b - 1)/(1 - x^c), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

v10.1

---

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your answer, which also differs from that of the other two Answers.

Comment: using version 10.1 result is precisely 0

Comment: I get george2079's answer using 10.1.  Neither it nor zero are correct.